# Matching and storing part of a string in a variable using JScript.NET

Tags: regex, jscript.net

I am fiddling with some a [script for Fiddler](http://fiddlerbook.com/Fiddler/dev/ScriptSamples.asp), which uses JScript.NET. I have a string of the format:

```
{"params":{"key1":"somevalue","key2":"someothervalue","key3":"whatevervalue", ...
```

I want to match and show `"key2":"someothervalue"` where `someothervalue` could be any value but the key is static.

Using good old `sed` and `bash` I can replace the part I am looking for with:

```
$ a='{"params":{"key1":"somevalue","key2":"someothervalue","key3":"whatevervalue", ...'
$ echo $a | sed -r 's/"key2":"[^"]+"/replaced/g'
{"params":{"key1":"somevalue",replaced,"key3":"whatevervalue", ...
```

Now. Instead of replacing it, I want to extract that part into a variable using JScript.NET. How can that be done?

Comment: I don't know much about JScript.NET, but parsing code with regex seems like a bad idea. Can't you load the script as an object? I'm a PHP man, the equivalent would be `json_decode($json)` - isn't there an option like this with JScript.NET?

Comment: It's certainly an alternative. I'd like to learn how to show regexp matches using JScript.NET though, as I will use the same method for showing other interesting stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most graceful way is to use a JSON parser.  My personal preference is to import IE's JSON parser using the `htmlfile` COM object.

```
import System;

var str:String = '{"params":{"key1":"foo","key2":"bar","key3":"baz"}}',
    htmlfile = new ActiveXObject('htmlfile');

// force htmlfile COM object into IE9 compatibility
htmlfile.IHTMLDocument2_write('<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" />');

// clone JSON object and methods into familiar syntax
var JSON = htmlfile.parentWindow.JSON,

// deserialize your JSON-formatted string
    obj = JSON.parse(str);

// access JSON values as members of a hierarchical object
Console.WriteLine("params.key2 = " + obj.params.key2);

// beautify the JSON
Console.WriteLine(JSON.stringify(obj, null, '\t'));
```

Compiling, linking, and running results in the following console output:

```
params.key2 = bar
{
        "params": {
                "key1": "foo",
                "key2": "bar",
                "key3": "baz"
        }
}
```

Alternatively, there are also at least a [couple of .NET namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18242429/1683264) which provide methods to serialize objects into a JSON string, and to deserialize a JSON string into objects.  Can't say I'm a fan, though.  The ECMAScript notation of `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` are certainly a lot easier and profoundly less alien than whatever neckbeard madness is [going on at Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

---

And while I certainly don't recommend scraping JSON (or any other hierarchical markup if it can be helped) as complicated text, JScript.NET will handle a lot of familiar Javascript methods and objects, including regex objects and regex replacements on strings.

sed syntax:

```
echo $a | sed -r 's/("key2"):"[^"]*"/\1:"replaced"/g'
```

JScript.NET syntax:

```
print(a.replace(/("key2"):"[^"]*"/, '$1:"replaced"'));
```

JScript.NET, just like JScript and JavaScript, also allows for calling a lambda function for the replacement.

```
print(
    a.replace(
        /"(key2)":"([^"]*)"/,

        // $0 = full match; $1 = (key2); $2 = ([^"]*)
        function($0, $1, $2):String {
            var replace:String = $2.toUpperCase();
            return '"$1":"' + replace + '"';
        }
    )
);
```

... Or to extract the value of `key2` using the `RegExp` object's `exec()` method:

```
var extracted:String = /"key2":"([^"]*)"/.exec(a)[1];
print(extracted);
```

Just be careful with that, though, as retrieving element `[1]` of the result of `exec()` will cause an index-out-of-range exception if there is no match.  Might either want to `if (/"key2":/.test(a))` or add a `try...catch`.  Or better yet, just do what I said earlier and deserialize your JSON into an object.

Comment: Not working for me if i use `htmlfile.parentWindow.JSON` before close it returns `undefined`

Comment: @MamdouhFreelance Did you do the `http-equiv="x-ua-compatible"` stuff and set compatibility to `"IE=9"`?  By default, JScript and JScript.NET load an older interpreter, one that does not include the `JSON` object and methods.  You must use the `meta` tag to force JScript.NET to load the Chakra engine.  Also, if you're using JScript through Windows Scripting Host and not the .NET flavor of JScript, you have to use `comObj.write` rather than the `comObj.IHTMLDocument2_write` method demonstrated above.  If this does not solve your problem, please create a new question post with full details.